# Wordpress plugin: add_submenu_page adds top level menu item

Tags: wordpress, navbar

I've created a menu with two submenu items. But with the code attached, it adds the top level name "management" as the first submenu item. How do I stop this?

```
class Personalize_Login_Plugin {

    public function __construct() {
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'my_admin_menu' ));
    }
    public function my_admin_menu() {
            add_menu_page( 'Project Management', 'Project Management', 'manage_options', 'testing_page', array( $this, 'my_admin_page' ), 'dashicons-star-filled', 6);
            add_submenu_page( 'testing_page', 'Trials', 'Trials', 'manage_options', 'sp-trials', array( $this, 'my_trials_page' ));
            add_submenu_page( 'testing_page', 'Enrolments', 'Enrolments', 'manage_options', 'sp-enrolments', array( $this, 'my_enrolments_page' ));
    }

    public function my_admin_page(){

        ?>
        <h3>Testing options</h3>
        <div>put more stuf here</div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
class Personalize_Login_Plugin {

    public function __construct() {
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'my_admin_menu' ));
    }
    public function my_admin_menu() {
            add_menu_page( 'Project Management', 'Project Management', 'manage_options', 'sp-trials', array( $this, 'my_admin_page' ), 'dashicons-star-filled', 6);
            add_submenu_page( 'sp-trials', 'Trials', 'Trials', 'manage_options', 'sp-trials', array( $this, 'my_trials_page' ));
            add_submenu_page( 'sp-trials', 'Enrolments', 'Enrolments', 'manage_options', 'sp-enrolments', array( $this, 'my_enrolments_page' ));
    }

    public function my_admin_page(){

        ?>
        <h3>Testing options</h3>
        <div>put more stuf here</div>
        <?php
    }
}

$Personalize_Login_Plugin = new Personalize_Login_Plugin();
```